# Hibernate set both crossed references on create

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, cross-reference

I have two entities, Project and ProjectFee:

```
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    //some more fields
    private Set<ProjectFees> fees = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

public class ProjectFee implements Serializable {
    //some more fields
    private Integer idProject; //id of the Project ProjectFee is related to
}
```

Mapped as:

```
<class name="com.package.Project" table="project">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <!-- more fields -->
    <set name="fees" table="project_fees" cascade="all" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="id_project"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.package.ProjectFees"/>
    </set>

</class>

<class name="com.package.ProjectFees" table="project_fees">
    <!-- more fields -->
    <property name="idProject" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_project" />
    </property>
</class>
```

So when I try to create a new Project and a new ProjectFee using the cascade I get an error because idProject cannot be null in db and it is not setted since Project is still not created so it hasn't id. I know I can solve it by doing, on create method:

1. Remove ProjectFees from Project
2. Create Project
3. Add ProjectFees to Project setting idProject for each one
4. Update Project

But this is kind of a "dirty" way so I would like to know if there is some way to do this automatically

Comment: Set references on both the sides of your relation and try persisting it.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan the issue is that I can't do that because I don't have Project.id since project doesn't exists in database yet

Answer (score 2):

Change your `ProjectFees` mapping to this:

```
<many-to-one name="idProject" class="com.gesmifid2.common.model.Project">
    <column name="id_project" />
</many-to-one>
```

---

Edit:

Your ProjectFee class should look like this:

```
public class ProjectFee implements Serializable {
    //some more fields
    private Project project; //project ProjectFee is related to
}
```

And every time you add new `ProjectFee` to the `Project`, you should set that `Project` in `ProjectFee`. Example of method in `Project` class:

```
public void addProjectFee( ProjectFee pf){
    fees.add(pf);
    pf.setProject(this);
}
```

Comment: Still the same error, `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id_project' cannot be null`

Comment: Yep, that would work but I only want to have the idProject, not the whole Project in ProjectFee

Comment: @Aldeguer Thats actually a way of handling database objects in ORM(bi-directional mapping). At your database side your will only get ids instead, in the corresponding tables.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I know that is a way to handle them but I need something different this time: not getting the whole object but the id instead

Comment: You can map the ID in addition to Project with "updateable=false, insertable=false" (needed because you will map the same column twice).

Answer (score 0):

If you closely look your `ProjectFee` class, there is no way for it to know that this is somehow related to class `Project` (as a foreign key `id_project`). That is why when you save both objects together, `ProjectFee` class dont know that it should populate the column `id_project` with id column value of `Project` class.

There are two possibilities -

1. Either you populate the `id_project` column by yourself (as you mentioned in question) by saving `Project` object first and then providing ID to the `ProjectFee` object.
2. Or, make a foreign key relation in you entities by making `id_project` property of type `Project` and join both entities on column `id/id_project`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The first one is what I am already doing and the second one is not valid this time since I want idProject to be Integer and not Project

Comment: If you want to `id_project` as an integer then you have to set it by yourself (as you are already doing) because automatically setting the value by framework will only work when you craete a bi-directional mapping (which you dont want to do).